# Setting Site wide Styles in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Fairly new to angular so I've probably missed this one when going through tutorials.

All I want to do is set the background color of the body tag. Site wide.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

write your style inside `style.css` in your src folder

Comment: Will that be packed automatically?

Comment: That's the angular way. This file will be loaded with your index.html sitewide

Comment: I don't have a styles.css file

Comment: Create it. If you create your project with the angularCLI the file will be automatically created

Comment: Yeah I created it, but it didn't pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `Angular CLI` than declare your style in the `component` decorator

```
@Component({
  styleUrls: [
   'stylesheetPath',
   'stylesheetPathTwo',
   ...
  ],
})
```

Or if you are going to use same `CSS` across whole project than just declare css in your `index.html`

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 
}
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not using that, using the pre build option in vs 2017 for angular 2 and asp core 2

Comment: So to give you context, I want to apply some font family accross the entire site. I tried to creating a styles.css and put a reference to in _layout.cshtml but that caused a web pack error

Comment: @BenDonnelly take a look on snippet above, you don't need to do anything with angular to apply styling, it is simple css

Comment: Yeah that is what I tried but webpack gives me an error in the console which I cant even view. It just says aborted.